# MySQL search (database)

Tags: mysql, database

How do i make a search in mysql that shows only the albums that theyre tracks are all made by diffrent composers ? (if they exist) **this is just an exemple**

I had already tried :

```
SELECT a.title, b.title, c.name
FROM fa_album a, fa_tracks b, fa_composer c
WHERE c.name!=a.artist
GROUP BY b.title
```

Comment: This sounds like a good scenario for a join. Have you ever worked with joins before?

Comment: No ):
Im kinda new to this ...

Comment: Ok well, re-reading your question, I would guess that what you're asking is impossible based on the implied database schema. You would need a one to one relationship between track and composer... I'm guessing that your current schema has a one to one relationship between album and composer. If your schema is setup correctly with the appropriate relationships, you would be able to do something like SELECT * FROM fa_tracks INNER JOIN fa_composer ON fa_tracks.composer = fa_composer.id WHERE fa_composer.id = ? GROUP BY fa_tracks.title; NB. I don't write raw SQL that often so I apologise for typos.

Comment: Yup ... its working ! 
Thanks a lot !! :)